# Summing a calculated control in Access continuous form

Tags: ms-access

I have a continuous form with two fields, weight and rate. For each record, I would like to find (weight/sum of all weights)*rate, and then sum these all up. I can get as far as putting a TotalWeight control in the footer, and the calculated control for each record displaying right. But then when I try to do the final sum in another footer control it gives me an #Error, and the calculated control says #Type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They have different rates. A simple case would be
(100, 90), (200, 80), Result: 83.33

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions must reference fields in RecordSource, not textboxes. Options:

1. do arithmetic calculation in a query that is form RecordSource then use that constructed field in aggregate function in textbox
2. repeat the entire arithmetic calculation in aggregate function

Comment: Oh weird, I was confused because it worked to sum the calculated control if the it wasn't also referencing the total weight. I put the calculations in a query and used that as the record source and that worked perfectly. Thank you!

Edit: except now the record source is not updateable. Don't have time to look at it now, but I'll have to try and solve that later.

Comment: Again, aggregate function cannot reference a control so "it worked to sum the calculated control" would not be possible. So something else was really happening. These sort of complex aggregate calcs are best done in a report.